# Redirect to subdomain and send same parameter using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect users who entered this type of url: mydomain.com/##UNIQUE_CODE## to my subdomain: app.mydomain.com/##UNIQUE_CODE##

```
##UNIQUE_CODE## -> [A-Za-z0-9-]{7} (eg. 7eld4ry)
```

So far I have this terrible code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Za-z0-9-]{7}
RewriteRule http://app.mydomain.com
```

So final example of what I want to achieve:

```
http://mydomain.com/7eld4ry ===redirect===> http://app.mydomain.com/7eld4ry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]{7})/?$ http://app.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Wow works perfectly! Would have never found this myself. Thanks!